# Dimensions Pythagoras Problem Solving Question

Tags: area, pythagorean-triples

[image: s]

[image]

I have no idea how to work for (b) (c). Help please? Step by Step solution?

Comment: Start by drawing a diagram, actually, two diagrams, one for each way to fit the booklet. Label all the relevant-looking line segments with numbers, if known, otherwise with letters. Write down equations relating the numbers and the letters. Solve the equations. Have a beer.

Comment: Yes, specifically which equations? I have attempted this but come up blank. Could you give me a step by step solution? Thanks so much

Comment: First, you wanted a start. Now, you want a step-by-step solution. Make up your mind.

Comment: A step by step solution please.

Comment: Good. But I don't do that. I'll find a question where someone wants hints, and spend my time there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the books are $20$ mm thick and the gap is $16$ mm, the  cosine of the gap angle is $\frac{16}{20}=0.8$.  This means the sine is $\sqrt{1-0.8^2}=\sqrt{.36}=.6$ and the height of the gap is $20\times0.6=12$.

Here, corrections were made when the question's author noted that 4 triangles at the base of the books were different from the one in the lower left corner. (See comments below)

The bottom of the box is $x+16+(4\times25)=x+116$, the height of the box is $y+12$, and $x+116=y+12$ so $y=x+104$.

The angles on the right side of box are the complimentary to those on the left so cosine is related to height and sine is related to the base.
The length of the books $(z)=\frac{1}{sin}x=\frac{1}{cos}y\quad\text{or}\quad \frac{5}{3}x=\frac{5}{4}y=\frac{5}{4}(x+104)$. Using the least common multiple, we get:

$$\frac{20}{12}x=\frac{15}{12}(x+104)\implies 5x=15\times104\implies x=3\times104 =312$$
The height of the book is a hypotenuse: $z=\frac{1}{sin}x=\frac{5}{3}x=\frac{5}{3}\times 312=520$

The width of a book equals the side of the box: $x+104=312+104=416$.

Comment: I don't think the gap below all of the books is 16mm... If you look at the diagram one is a right angled triangle with the right angle at the bottom while the other has it at the top, with the base being 20 mm rather than the hypotenuse.

Comment: You are correct. The base is now the hypotenuse of a triangle whose cosine side is $20$ and $\frac{20}{0.8}=25$.  This means the bottom of the box is $\quad x+4\times25+16=x+116\quad y=x+102\quad $and so on.

Comment: In catching these errors, it shows you are thinking and trying. That is a great habit to have on MSE and will get you more upvotes than you've been getting before.

Comment: Thanks; final thing - is there a way to solve for x without using trigonometry (pythag)?

Comment: The terms cosine and sine are just names. Just think of side ratios and forget that they are part of trig. I don't see how this is solvable without these ratios. And they are not hard as demonstrated by your spotting the gap difference in Part c.

Comment: @poetasis I just figured out & was just starting to answer the duplicate at [Pythagoras Problem Solving Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3572172/602049) when I saw the vote to mark it as a duplicate come in. I used basically the same method you did, although in a somewhat different way. However, I got the same the same answers as you, i.e., a book width of $284$ and a height of $340$.

Comment: @global05 I want to caution you about something I learned in my first year of college back in 1969 and in electronics, programming, and mechanics since then. Sometimes quizzes, textbooks, training videos and manuals contain errors that the authors missed. Sometimes the "correct" answer is the book answer instead of what is derived from fixing a mistake. Just a warning in case the book answer matches my first interpretation.

Comment: @global05 Note I actually didn't directly use any sines or cosines in my answer but, instead, used the ratios that come from similar triangles. Nonetheless, it's still effectively the same method as poetasis used in this answer.

Comment: @JohnOmielan could you please tell me the steps of your method?

Comment: @global05 The steps I used are not really that different from this answer, except instead of using sines or cosines, I used the equivalent side length ratios due to similar triangles.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yes, but could you show me which triangles are similar?

Comment: @global05 The triangle showing in the lower left in your question, i.e., the $12-16-20$ one (which is just $4$ times the standard $3-4-5$ one) is similar to the triangle in the upper right corner, i.e, where the top of the fifth book is lying against the side of the cube, and also the larger triangle formed between the visible underside of the fifth book, the bottom left side (i.e., the one with the $16$ mm showing in your diagram) and the connecting vertical edge in the middle of the diagram.

Comment: @JohnOmielan if I have understood you correctly I don't understand how this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Part a.

The Pythagorean Theorem works for any number of dimensions. $$a^2+b^2+c^2=d^2\quad \text{where}\quad a=b=c\quad\implies 3a^2=d^2$$
so... letting $\quad d=500mm\quad a=\text{box side length, then}\quad a=\frac{d}{\sqrt{3}}=\frac{500}{\sqrt{1.732...}}\approx 288.675...$

Part b.

The width of the rectangular envelope is the same length as the square envelope's side. At a $45^\circ$ angle say, to the right, you have an isosceles triangle in the upper left where the base is the width of the envelope, call it $W$. The sum of the squares of the equal sides $S$ of the triangle equals the width of the envelope squared.

$$S^2+S^2=2S^2=W^2\implies S=\sqrt{\frac{W^2}{2}}=\frac{W}{\sqrt{2}}$$
Now, the isosceles triangle in the upper right has a side length $s=W-S$ and the base of that triangle is the height of the envelope $h$ is the square root of $2s^2$.

$$h^2=2s^2=2(W-S)^2\implies h=\sqrt{2}(W-S)=\sqrt{2}\biggl(\frac{\sqrt{2}W-W}{\sqrt{2}}\biggr)=W(\sqrt{2}-1)$$

In all of this, $W=120mm$. Can you take it from here?

[image]

$$$$

Part c.

Without a picture, it is impossible to know what $tilting$ means or where the gap is.

Comment: Thanks so much... I have attached a picture for (c) as you requested

Comment: Doesn't S = sqrt(W^2/2)? Not sqrt(W/2)?

Comment: And if so is the answer 21cm? Thanks

Comment: Good call. It's easy to miss things like that sometimes.

Comment: So is my answer correct? What about for c? I don't follow the trigonometry; is there a simpler way to do it or if not could you explain exactly how the trigonometry works? Thanks so much.

Comment: I didn't plug in the dimensions. You have to trust yourself at some point. I'm working on the mistake you spotted for Part c now.

Answer (score 1):

The right triangles in this problem are all $3,4,5$ triangles.

In the lower left corner, the vertical side of the right triangle is $12$ mm.
You were given that the horizontal side is $16$ mm.
Then you have (as you know) four right triangles along the bottom edge with hypotenuse $25$ mm.

Let the width of the book (the hypotenuse of the large triangle on the lower right) be $L$ mm. Then the other two sides of that right triangle are
$\frac35 L$ mm and $\frac45 L$ mm.

Now along the bottom edge you have sides of one small triangle, four slightly larger ones, and one large triangle. You know the first five lengths and have a formula for the last one.
Along the right edge you have sides of one small triangle and one large one.

Write a formula for the total length along the bottom edge.
Write a formula for the total length along the right edge.
Then, since the box is a cube, you know the two formulas must be equal.
You should end up with one equation in one variable. Solve it.

Finally, you plug into one of your formulas to get the side of the cube, because that's the length of the book.

Comment: How do you know the right angled triangles are 3, 4, 5 triangles?

Comment: One of the triangles has hypotenuse $20$ and one leg of length $16.$ That's a ratio of $5:4$ and it tells you right away that you have a $3,4,5$ triangle, by which I mean the sides of the triangle are proportional to those numbers, (You can also work out the third side, $12$, using the Pythagorean Theorem and observe the ratios then.) Use plane geometry on the face of the box to find congruent angles, and you should find that the triangles formed by the edges of the books and the edges of the box are all similar to each other.