# What is the proof the two triangles are similar and what is the length, width and height of the book?

Tags: geometry, triangles, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

[image]
There are five copies of a book each 20mm thick. When tilted, they fit snugly inside a cubic box with a gap of 16mm at the bottom left as shown.

I struggled with this in a recent practice paper, any help appreciated.

Comment: An earlier question about the same issue is at [Dimensions Pythagoras Problem Solving Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3566153/602049).